# Does rsync -D protect the root partition uuid in fstab?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, rsync

I have a few partitions. One is for my main OS installation, and a second is set aside as the destination for a backup of the main OS. I have a secondary OS set aside for maintenance purposes, with both of the aforementioned partitions mounted as /source and /dest respectively.

After a successful run of:

```
sudo rsync -av --del /source /dest
```

I noticed that the fstab file in the copy has a different uuid for the root partition than the original, but, why?

Does it have anything to do with the `-a` argument being equivalent to `-rlptgoD`, with `-D` being `--devices --specials`?

I need to be sure I'm doing what I intend to do for this copy operation.

Answer (score 2):

`rsync` does not change any files, so if you did the `rsync` correctly, you should expect `/source/etc/fstab` to be identical to `/dest/etc/fstab`.

It looks like your `rsync` command copies `/source` to `/dest/source` instead of `/dest` which you would expect. So if you check in your partitions, you probably have a file `/dest/source/etc/fstab` which is the actual copy of `/source/etc/fstab`, (`/dest/etc/fstab` just happens to be there with the old data).

To copy directories the way you want, you need to add a trailing `/` in the source (I usually add one also in the destination, but I believe that is not necessarily needed), like this:

```
sudo rsync -av --del /source/ /dest/
```

Relevant documentation from the man page:

> ```
>           rsync -avz foo:src/bar /data/tmp
>
>    This  would  recursively  transfer all files from the directory src/bar on the ma‐
>    chine foo into the /data/tmp/bar directory on the local  machine.  The  files  are
>    transferred  in  "archive"  mode,  which ensures that symbolic links, devices, at‐
>    tributes, permissions, ownerships, etc. are preserved in the transfer.   Addition‐
>    ally,  compression  will be used to reduce the size of data portions of the trans‐
>    fer.
>
>           rsync -avz foo:src/bar/ /data/tmp
>    A trailing slash on the source changes this behavior to avoid  creating  an  addi‐
>    tional  directory  level  at  the destination.  You can think of a trailing / on a
>    source as meaning "copy the contents of this directory" as opposed  to  "copy  the
>    directory  by  name", but in both cases the attributes of the containing directory
>    are transferred to the containing directory on the destination.  In  other  words,
>    each  of  the following commands copies the files in the same way, including their
>    setting of the attributes of /dest/foo:
>
>           rsync -av /src/foo /dest
>           rsync -av /src/foo/ /dest/foo
> ```